# How to allow any user to upload a video in a my youtube channel using youtube API?

Tags: node.js, oauth-2.0, oauth, youtube-api

I have made an web app using MERN Stack that allows users to input title, description and upload a file using YouTube Data API v3. After uploading the file, a new window opens which asks for signin. After an user signin, the video is uploaded to the owner's youtube account. But the problem is owner has to add the uploader mail id as  a "Trusted User" in "OAuth consent screen" in google cloud platform. But if a random user with a unknowns mail id wants to upload a file using my app, how can I able to give access to him/her? How he/she can able to upload a file to my youtube channel?  And I am not asking them to create an account on my app to upload video.

Comment: Basically, what you're trying to achieve is not allowed by YouTube, neither by using the Web UI, nor by employing the YouTube Data API. That's because the YouTube's system does not permit **anonymous** video uploading: one is allowed to upload videos only upon he/she being rightfully authenticated within this system (this implies that he/she already has an YouTube account).

Comment: I read somewhere about it may be done using  server side(API) application. What your thoughts in this?

Comment: @BalabhadraChand add where do you read about that.